# Close access to website by http://ip, but allow by http://domain

Tags: apache-2.2

I have to close access to website by ip (close access via http://203.0.113.11), but access via domain should be still available.

I've read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html (section `Using Name-based Virtual Hosts`), configured as recommended:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

restarted httpd, but this `VirtualHost` is still available by ip.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Changed IP address to one within an RFC 3330 TEST-NET example range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your apache will always use the first virtualhost as the default one.

So before any other vhosts, create another one that points to whichever you want to show all visitors hitting a hostname that doesn't exist within a virtualhost config.

Comment: Thank you! I've added VirtualHost with <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/blogs/"
    <Directory "/home/blogs/">
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>